# How to get a list or library name if you have the full url of the list only?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

SO I Have the list or libraru URL. Now i am trying to get the title of the list or library. not all the time the URl has the same title has the list or library has 
here is my example

```
 https://example.org/siteone/subsiteone/subsitetwo/Lists/ED/DispForm.aspx
```

here the list url is "ED"

but the list name is Employee Details
how do i get the name using rest or jquery

i need to dynamically get the list name

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/_api/web/lists?$expand=RootFolder&$select=Title,RootFolder/ServerRelativeURL&$filter=substringof('List1',RootFolder/ServerRelativeURL) eq true
```